# Trouble with POSTing JSON to endpoint

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to submit a POST request containing JSON to a given endpoint.  However the below code sends me to a login page which is the default functionality for all non-/api endpoints.  Because [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) doesn't direct me to the login page but correctly hits the API, I'm assuming the problem is in this C# code.

```
    Dim RemoteUrl As String = "https://my-site.com/api/tournament/results"
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim xmlHttpReq As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(RemoteUrl), HttpWebRequest)
    xmlHttpReq.Method = "POST"
    xmlHttpReq.ContentType = "application/json"

    With (New StreamWriter(xmlHttpReq.GetRequestStream))

         .Write(Json)
         .Flush()
         .Close()

Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(xmlHttpReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    With (New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream))
       result = .ReadToEnd
    End With
End With
```

Any idea what steps I need to take to debug this?

Comment: @Jasen Doh!  Thx

Comment: I guess I'd start with the HTTP Status Code and try to capture the request and response headers.